# App crashes with kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException when I get value from Spinner

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, spinner, android-adapter, android-viewbinding

My app works without errors and updates the field in the `firestore` when I hard-coded the value that needs to be updated. However, when I the following code to get the value from the `spinner` to update a field in the firestore, the app crashes.

I am using `kotlin` and `viewBinding`.

Following is the error in the `Logcat`

> ```
> --------- beginning of crash 2021-06-07 14:00:12.155 23175-23175/com.trad E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.trad, PID: 23175
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
>     at com.trad.ui.adapters.OrderStatusListAdapter.access$getBinding$p(OrderStatusListAdapter.kt:32)
>     at com.trad.ui.adapters.OrderStatusListAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(OrderStatusListAdapter.kt:84)
>     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
>     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
>     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
>     at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
>     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
> ```
>
> 2021-06-07 14:00:12.234 23175-23175/com.trad I/Process: Sending
> signal. PID: 23175 SIG: 9

Following is the `OrderStatusListAdapter.kt` class
The error that is pointing at line number 32 and 84 are mentioned as a comment in the code.

```
open class OrderStatusListAdapter(         //LINE # 32 MENTIONED IN THE ERROR
        private val context: Context,
        private var list: ArrayList<OrderStatus>,
    
        ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
        lateinit var newOrderStatus: Spinner
        private lateinit var binding: OrderStatusLayoutBinding
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            return MyViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.order_status_layout,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val model = list[position]
    
            if (holder is MyViewHolder) {
    
                GlideLoader(context).loadProductPicture(
                    model.image,
                    holder.itemView.iv_order_status_item_image
                )
    
                val dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"
                
                val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    
                val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                calendar.timeInMillis = model.order_datetime
    
                val orderDateTime = formatter.format(calendar.time)
                holder.itemView.tv_order_status_order_date.text = orderDateTime
    
    
                holder.itemView.tv_order_status_item_name.text = model.items[0].title
                holder.itemView.tv_order_status_item_price.text = "$${model.total_amount}"
 model.order_datetime.toString()
                holder.itemView.tv_order_status.text = model.order_status
                holder.itemView.tv_order_status_order_id.text = model.id
    
                holder.itemView.btn_order_status_change_status.setOnClickListener {
    
    binding.spnOrderChangeStatus.onItemSelectedListener = // LINE 84 MENTIONED IN THE ERROR
                        object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                            override fun onItemSelected(
                                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                                view: View?,
                                position: Int,
                                id: Long
                            ) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    context,
                                    "Selected value is ${
                                        parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                                    }",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
    
                                val newstat = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                                FirestoreClass().updateOrderStatus(model.id, newstat)
    
                            }
    
                            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
    
                            }
                        }
                }
    
                holder.itemView.ib_order_status_delete_product.visibility = View.GONE
    
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(context, SoldProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SOLD_PRODUCT_DETAILS, model)
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                }
    
    
            }
    
        }
    
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }
    
    
        class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
    }
```

Comment: Crashes typically display some sort of error messages in the debugger. So what's the error?

Comment: `Logcat` and adapter class added in the question and error lines mentioned in the code as a comment.

Comment: Well, the error says it quite clear: Your property `binding` is not initalized when you try to access it ...

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix it? I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized`

Means that you tried to use the `binding` property before it being initialized.

`binding` should be declared in the place where you define the layout; and this is typically in `onCreateViewHolder()` callback at which you defined the default inflater without using data binding, to fix that:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

    // initialize the binding either use:
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.order_status_layout, parent, false) 
    // or use:
    // binding = OrderStatusLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater)

    return MyViewHolder(binding)
}
```

The second issue: you accept a `View` as constructor parameter in `MyViewHolder` while it should accept the item binding type which is `OrderStatusLayoutBinding`

> `class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)`

To fix that:

```
class MyViewHolder(binding: OrderStatusLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

**UPDATE**

> I got the `error Unresolved reference: DataBindingUtil alsoDataBindingUtil and inflater in binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.order_status_layout, parent, false) are red.`

You need to enable dataBinding in build.gradle (Module level) and this requires to have `kotlin-kapt` plugin:

```
plugins {
    …
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
android {
    …
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the error `Unresolved reference: DataBindingUtil` also`DataBindingUtil` and `inflater` in `binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.order_status_layout, parent, false)` are red.

Comment: Please use this instead  *binding = OrderStatusLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater)*

Comment: Logcat, 'Unresolved reference: inflater' and `inflater` in the bracket is red too.

Comment: This is what my `onCreateViewHolder` now look like.

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        binding = OrderStatusLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

Comment: Are Sure you enabled binding library in build.gradle?

Comment: I have     `buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }` in my 'build.gradle(Module)'

Comment: @Codist Please replace `viewBinding true` to `dataBinding true`

Comment: @Codist I just updated that in the answer.. Please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233526/discussion-between-codist-and-zain).

Answer (score 1):

The crash has occurred, because the binding is not initialized. Change the ViewHolder constructors:

```
class MyViewHolder(private val binding : OrderStatusLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

Also change onCreateViewHolder method

```
 return ViewHolder(OrderStatusLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent,false))
```

Comment: I commented out the last line of code and added your first line of code there and commented out the entire code inside `override fun onCreateViewHolder` and added your second line of code. Errors in `Logcat` is `Cannot create an instance of an abstract class` and `Type mismatch: inferred type is OrderStatusLayoutBinding but View was expected`. Then I renamed ` return ViewHolder` to  `return MyViewHolder` then the errors are gone. But when I hit the button the app still crashes like before and Logcat errors remain the same as mentioned in my question.

Comment: add inner in front of class MyViewHolder and try to run it.
inner class MyViewHolder

Comment: I made the changes as you said but the errors are the same as in my question. It's pointing at the same lines of code after making all these changes to my initial code.